# XPaths in Internet Explorer and their difference to Xpaths in Chrome, Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, xpath

I got following Xpaths:

```
IE: //body/div[2]/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]
IE Compressed:                                           //div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]
Chrome:                 /html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]
Firefox:                /html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]
```

I already read the Xpath specifications and something about that in IE 5,6,7,8,9 the first node is[0], but according to W3C, it is [1]. I understand how the Xpaths are build for Firefox and Chrome, but i can't understand how it works in IE? How can it even work?

I have to work with IE for a project...

Comment: whatever you are doing those xpaths are super brittle.  Make sure to use other techniques like the id and class to identify items if this is code that will stick around and not just training.

Comment: IE did not support XHTML at all until version 9 so I'm betting that has something to do with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different browsers have different engines, Chrome adds his tags, also if page has error in tags Chrome likes to finish them. Also websites are usualy created with different layouts as same website can look different in different browsers. For that they use different `.css` . As working expereance I had with IE (c# .net) I used FF extention FireBug and his addon FirePath its awesome tool for creating xpath.